# Rails 3 has_many order_by and group_by not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following association in my `Group` model:

```
has_many :subscriptions, :order => 'subscriptions.expiration_date DESC', :group => 'subscriptions.product_name', :conditions => ['subscriptions.status IN (?)', [:active, :canceled]]
```

The Models (User, Subscription, Group) break down like this:

```
**User**
has_many :groups, :before_add => :validates_group, :through => :group_users, :conditions => ["groups_users.status = ?", 'active']
**Group**
has_many :users, :through => :group_users, :conditions => ['groups_users.status = ?', 'active']
has_many :subscriptions, :order => 'subscriptions.expiration_date DESC', :group => 'subscriptions.product_name', :conditions => ['subscriptions.status IN (?)', [:active, :canceled]]
**Subscription**
belongs_to :group
```

So, a group could have multiple subscriptions (for different products; subscription.product_name) for the same product (depending on if they renewed or it was just an old one in the system). The `has_many :subscriptions` order_by is not working properly.

**For Example:**
If the user has 3 subscriptions (One for product X and 2 for product Y). And you run the following

Subscriptions Method in User Model:

```
 def subscriptions
    subs = []
    groups.collect(&:subscriptions).each do |sub|
      if sub
        subs << sub
      end
    end
    subs.flatten!
  end

u = User.last
u.subscriptions
```

The one for product X comes back fine, but when it pulls back product Y it is pulling back the first one in the list (the one with the expiration date in the past).

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I am trying to explain it the best I can. Anyone run into this situation where order and group are not working properly on an association?